# Can't stop animation occurring in MPMoviePlayerController when done is pressed

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, animated

I'm trying to prevent the transition animation that occurs when you exit a video in MPMoviePLayerController when the user presses done. I can stop it fine when the movie finishes on its own using the moviePlayBackDidFinish: notification but for some reason when I try it in the exact same way with the exitedFullscreen: notification (which responds to a done press) it doesn't work, as in, the animation occurs.

Here is the complete code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
-(void) playvideo
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"MOV"]];
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
}



-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
{
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];


}


- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {

    moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: Call setFullScreen: animated before removeFromSuperview ... [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work, I'd tried that before anyway but its effectively the same code. I think its an Apple bug as there's no logical reason why it would work perfectly for the moviePlayBackDidFinish: notification and not for the exitedFullscreen: notification

Answer (score 0):

you can to remove animation using this code .

```
 -(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
    {


      [moviePlayer stop];
      [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
      moviePlayer = nil;


    }


    - (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {

        [moviePlayer stop];
        [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
        moviePlayer = nil;

    }
```